# End of line check for <br />

Tags: php, mysql, select, while-loop

In PHP I'm trying to display a row's content with a maximum character limit, so

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `news`");

$length = 350; // Show first 350 characters of row, then cut it off

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$show = nl2br(substr($row['content'], 0, $length));
}
```

P.S: The code tags are messing up for me, $length isn't in the while loop.

Using a while() statement to to increase $length with strpos, doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

I want to do this, in case the line has a link in it, it won't cut it off, until it goes to a new line, and it knows it's finished, so the link will be complete.

Comment: [`text-overflow`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/textoverflow.html) might be useful.

Answer (score 2):

i can't give you a short answer to that problem, because it's difficult...
frameworks like Symfony already have that function built-in (take a look at `truncate` in smarty, symfony etc.)

but i found a useful function example: [HERE -- truncate($text, $length = 100, $ending = '...', $exact = false, $considerHtml = true)](http://dodona.wordpress.com/2009/04/05/how-do-i-truncate-an-html-string-without-breaking-the-html-code/)

Comment: I'll have to look into some, the function looks exactly like what I need, I'll read it and such, but going to go through some frameworks with a truncating function. I appreciate it, thanks.

Comment: i have to add here (to be complete), that the problem is the EXACT match of the opening to the closing tag while scanning for tags...

this *CAN* be done with RegEx and Backreferences, but this will blow up this question a lot ;)

Answer (score 0):

Do it on the server side. I would also advise against `SELECT`ing `*` (all). Always use a column list.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT SUBSTR(content, 0, 350) AS content FROM `news`");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    $show = nl2br($row['content']);
}
```

And as always, please [stop using](http://www.deprecatedphp.com/mysql) `mysql_` functions.

**Update**

I neglected to read the entire requirement. This should work:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN LOCATE('</a>', content) > 350 THEN SUBSTRING(@str, 1, LOCATE('</a>', content)+4)
        ELSE SUBSTRING(content, 1, 350)
    END
FROM `news`
```

Comment: totally not the point here?
the *REAL* question is: "how to truncate text without breaking TAGS in it"

Comment: What "TheHe" said is what I'm looking for, and the code I posted isn't the actual code I'm using, similar, but not the same, I haven't used mysql in a while.

Answer (score 0):

Write into a div box with limited width:

```
<div style="width=100px; display: inline-block;">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$show = nl2br(substr(trim(strip_tags($row['content'])), 0, $length));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS:

```
.wrap-link {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

This way, instead of chopping off the link text or manually wrapping the line based on an arbitrary character limit (which would be inconsistent anyway), any word that's longer than the width of its container (e.g. a long url) will be forced to wrap automatically.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you want to generate a teaser for an article or something similar. I use a combination of a `generate_teaser` function that basically does a `substr` without cutting the text in the middle of a word or a sentence and a `close_tags` function that tries (and often succeeds) to close the tags (warning: it will probably fail to close tables correctly). Currently I can't give you the code that I use, but I can tell you that it's inspired by (and improved on) these two implementations: [`node_teaser`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_teaser/6) and [`closetags`](http://snipplr.com/view/3618/close-tags-in-a-htmlsnippet/).